# k-means clustering, Why “KeyError: 0” in the code below:

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining

I used this code with my dataset (CSV), but it was originally (Bloops Data) as below:
"X_train, _ = make_blobs (n_samples = 500, centers = 3, n_features = 2, random_state = 20)"

**the error in** (assign_cluster function "cluster = assign_cluster(k, X, cg_prev)" –)

And I think that the error occurred for this reason, I hope to get the answer.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from pandas import DataFrame

X_train= pd.read_csv("/content/veriseti.csv")

##Visualize the data##
df = DataFrame(dict(x=X_train.iloc[:, 0], y=X_train.iloc[:,1]))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
df.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y')
plt.xlabel('X_1')
plt.ylabel('X_2')
plt.show()

##functions for K-means
def init_centroids(k, X):
    arr = []
    for i in range(k):
        cx1 = np.random.uniform(min(X.iloc[:,0]), max(X.iloc[:,0]))
        cx2 = np.random.uniform(min(X.iloc[:,1]), max(X.iloc[:,1]))
        arr.append([cx1, cx2])
    return np.asarray(arr)

def dist(a, b):
    return np.sqrt(sum(np.square(a-b)))

def assign_cluster(k, X, cg):
    cluster = [-1]*len(X)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        dist_arr = []
        for j in range(k):
            dist_arr.append(dist(X[i], cg[j]))
        idx = np.argmin(dist_arr)
        cluster[i] = idx
    return np.asarray(cluster)

def compute_centroids(k, X, cluster):
    cg_arr = []
    for i in range(k):
        arr = []
        for j in range(len(X)):
            if cluster[j]==i:
                arr.append(X[j])
        cg_arr.append(np.mean(arr, axis=0))
    return np.asarray(cg_arr)

def measure_change(cg_prev, cg_new):
    res = 0
    for a,b in zip(cg_prev,cg_new):
        res+=dist(a,b)
    return res

def show_clusters(X, cluster, cg):
    df = DataFrame(dict(x=X_train.iloc[:, 0], y=X_train.iloc[:, 1], label=cluster))
    colors = {0:'blue', 1:'orange', 2:'green',3:'green',4:'green'}
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    grouped = df.groupby('label')
    for key, group in grouped:
        group.plot(ax=ax, kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', label=key, color=colors[key])
    ax.scatter(cg.iloc[:, 0], cg.iloc[:, 0], marker='*', s=150, c='#ff2222')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.show()

##K-means
def k_means(k, X):
    cg_prev = init_centroids(k, X)
    cluster = [0]*len(X)
    cg_change = 100
    while cg_change>.001:
        cluster = assign_cluster(k, X, cg_prev)
        show_clusters(X, cluster, cg_prev)
        cg_new = compute_centroids(k, X, cluster)
        cg_change = measure_change(cg_new, cg_prev)
        cg_prev = cg_new
    return cluster

cluster = k_means(5, X_train)
```

**This is the error message:**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ericl16384 sir..My data is in two columns and I want to make a clustering and visualization for it by K-means

Comment: I should have read the title. Sorry.